# Using Python to parse the Time from a Date and Time column, without affecting the Date

Tags: python, date, datetime, csv, time

I am using Python to clean up a CSV file to be imported into Access, and one of the errors I get relates to a column that is supposed to be a Date format, but is instead a Date/Time format.  A typical cell looks like this:

```
08/02/2012 02:35p
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
08/02/2012
```

And am having trouble figuring out exactly how to do that.  All of the data is in the same Column, if that helps.

Clarification: The CSV file I'm modifying has many fields, several of which regard dates, hwoever, this is the only column with the time also included.  I need to fix the entire column so it drops the time off of it, with out changing the date, and also with out affecting the other dates in each line.
So it looks more like this:

```
Name, Check-inDate, Check-outDate, AppointmentScheduled, Billed
Frank Stalone, 08/15/2012, 08/18/2012, 08/02/2012 02:35p, 08/22/2012
```

and all i wanna do is get rid of the " 02:35p"

(on a side note, what I really wish I could do is fix the ridiculously broken program that gives us these reports which aren't formatted correctly to begin with, but THE MAN won't let us do that :/ )

Edit in response to comments:
The time is consistent.  It is always MM/DD/YYYY space HH:MM a/p. so, essentially, i could jsut remove the last 7 characters from the field and it would give the desired result.

Comment: How consistent is the format?  That is, is it the wrong values (date/time instead of just date) but always written with a space after the date, or are there many different variations?

Comment: *affecting*... not effecting.

Comment: (an aside on your aside)how exactly would you propose fixing said program? do you have the required skill set to do that? have you tried contacting the developers of the software with your grievances? you would be surprised sometimes at the willingness of software developers to want to improve their software ;)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Great idea in general, but it sounds like in this case he'd have to convince the man (his manager? his prof? Lou Reed's heroin dealer?") before that would help…

Comment: I am not allowed to directly contact the people who made this thing.  I work for a governemnt agency and it was contracted to the lowest bidder and, from what I understand from my boss, the agency would have to pay more for them to fix it.  Having a moron do the contracting without input from the people who use the program is also how the program ONLY runs correctly in IE9 and the reports it exports are in formats that need heavy modifying in order to fit into our other databases.  I'm jsut a clerk trying to make a shortcut so this is less cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date = "08/02/2012 02:35p"
print date.split()[0]
```

but surely thats not all you are looking for ...

maybe

```
import time

date = "08/02/2012 02:35p"
t = time.strptime(date.replace("p","pm").replace("a","am"),"%m/%d/%y %I:%M%p")
my_desired_time_format = "%m/%d/%Y"
print time.strftime(my_desired_time_format,t)
```

would be better

To do what you want you would use something like

```
import re
with open('some.csv','r') as fin:
     data = re.sub("(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}) \d{2}:\d{2}[ap]","\\1",fin.read())
with open('fixed.csv','w') as fout:
     fout.write(data)
```

although it would probably be better to do with awk or sed (if you are on an OS that has those)

Comment: I'd use `datetime` rather than `time`, parse the original string with `datetime.datetime.strptime`, convert it to a `date` with `d = dt.date()`, and format the result with `d.strftime`… but otherwise, yeah, that's the answer if you really need to "parse" things. And, if that isn't necessary, then `split` is the answer.

Comment: what advantages does that give? I usually use time, but no particular reason for using it over datetime typically...

Comment: Well, `datetime` works outside of 1970-2038, handles microseconds, has separate types for days vs. timepoints vs. diffs etc., can handle timezones (if you get the `tzinfo` from outside the stdlib), gets updated (or, more often, gets argued about until everyone decides it's OK) more often, etc. On the other hand, `time` gives you values you can, e.g., pass to `ctypes` or `struct` onto a network stream more easily. Probably none of those tradeoffs matter in the OP's use case, but the 1970-2038 seems most likely to if anything does.

Comment: oh yeah ... now I remember why I would sometimes use datetime :) thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: Somewhere, there's a writeup by Tim Peters on the differences between the two, which is both more informative and much more entertaining. Also, as of 3.2 (and 2.7? I forget…), `datetime` has a very readable pure-Python implementation (with C acceleration), while `time` is written in C, and mostly depends on C/POSIX APIs, so in some cases you need to read the manages (which is especially fun on Windows) to understand what it's doing. On the other hand, the pure Python code itself is documented with "see this Zope wiki page that hasn't existed in 5 years", so…

Comment: ok, that looks fine, however, and I supposed i shoudl ahve clarified this better, the part i'm relaly having dificulty with is getting it to modify only that one column.  I'll edit my question so it better asks the question I need asked. Thank you.

Comment: based on your edit I think sed or awk or something may be a better choice than python for this... that said its doable... but you have to read in the whole file and then rewrite it... I'll edit my answer to reflect how to do it in python

Comment: Thanks! That worked great! It fixed that one column wiht out messing with any of the other date columns, and when I went to import it into the Access Database, I no longer got over 2000 errors, only 2 (caused by someone skipping some fields).  Only thing is that when you open the initial file as fin, you need to make it readable (r, not w):
with open('some.csv','r') as fin:

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, you can get the date-part of a datetime object using the member function [datetime.datetime.date()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date).

Here's an example (the parsing is done using [dateutil.parser](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c), but you can use [datetime.datetime.strptime()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) as well.):

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> s = "08/02/2012 02:35p"
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(s)
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 2, 14, 35)
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(s).date()
datetime.date(2012, 8, 2)
```

On a sidenote, this approach can handle the correct entries as well:

```
>>> s = "08/02/2012"
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(s).date()
datetime.date(2012, 8, 2)
```